# Python "and" operator with ints

Tags: python, boolean

What is the explanation for this behavior in Python?

```
a = 10
b = 20
a and b # 20
b and a # 10
```

`a and b` evaluates to 20, while `b and a` evaluates to 10. Are positive ints equivalent to True? Why does it evaluate to the second value? Because it is second?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) explains this quite well:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

And similarly for `or` which will probably be the next question on your lips.

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Answer (score 4):

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```
x and y     if x is false, then x, else y
```

non-zero integers are treated as boolean true, so you get exactly the behavior described in the docs:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 20
>>> a and b
20
>>> b and a
10
```

Answer (score 0):

In python everything that is not None, 0, False, "", [], (), {} is True

a and b is readed as True and True in this case
the same for b and a

and yes in this case it takes the first value

edit: incomplete as in the comments

Comment: By "first" do you mean "second"?

Comment: I don't think it is "taking" the first value. I think it is evaluating to the second value in the expression. Can anyone point me to a resource that explains this? (Thanks Dave!)

Comment: This isn't quite right. `[]` is `False`, for example. The evaluation is done by calling `__nonzero__` in Python 2 or `__bool__` in Python 3.

Comment: @Mike Your question contained a mistake. The values you said were returned by these expression were not correct. I've fixed it now, but it probably explains the confusion here.

Comment: `None, 0, False, "", [], (), {}` and custom types where `__bool__` (py3) or `__nonzero__` (py2) return False are all considered False.