# Why does python return false with this statement?

Tags: python, boolean, operators

When printing statements like:

```
print(2 + 3 and 4 > 12)
```

the output is `False`. I can't understand why and how `5 and False` returns `False`. Can anyone please explain how its being evaluated? How does integers and booleans interact?

Comment: Because *anything* `and False` is `False`

Comment: What *would* you expect it to return?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  You need to repeat your materials on basic Boolean logic.

Comment: @Nick I understood that. But why a number `and False` is `False`. I mean, how is it evaluated by the compiler?

Comment: @Shounak because 5 is "truthy". See this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: Again, this is already covered in documentation on evaluating Boolean expressions.  Please refer to those materials and point out exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: Because, boolean is a subclass of integer for historical reasons. In python 3.x, 0 is false and 1 is true. Other integers also assert 'true' e.g. if 3: print('yayy true')

Comment: See the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: @Muhammad `bool` being a subclass of `int` is irrelevant here and does not contribute to this result.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9299079/476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean `A and B` is only true when both `A` and `B` are true. In this case, `5` is "truthy", but False is, well, not true.